# Get 'revert ds-math-sub-underflow' with removeLiquidity func

Tags: uniswap, ganache

I deployed Uniswap contracts locally on Ganache. I was able to addLiquidity, process different swaps, but I can't now remove that liquidity. I just get 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ds-math-sub-underflow'.

I know that possibly I have to approve LP tokens to router contract, but I don't know how to do that properly. Because I manually deployed only Factory and Router.

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem by deploying my own contract that abstractly looks like this:

```
import "./../router/libraries/SafeMath.sol";
import "./../core/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Approver {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    // returns sorted token addresses, used to handle return values from pairs sorted in this order
    function sortTokens(address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address token0, address token1) {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2Library: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
        (token0, token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    }

    // calculates the CREATE2 address for a pair without making any external calls
    function pairFor(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address pair) {
        (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                hex'ca29708fdd31b503262d6a40c70a2bf4316b0193e0b6df6e194e1cbcfb0b4bde' // don't forget to change this init code on your specific 
            ))));
    }

    function approve(address from) public { //set account you added liquidity from address
        address pair = pairFor(factory_address,tokenA_address,tokenB_address);
        (bool result) = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).approve(from,router02_address,value); // send liquidity to pair
        require(result, "failed");
    }
```

You can just call approve() func and try to remove liquidity method again.

Hope it'll help someone)